# Jon Raasch jQuery Slideshow Script failed to work for me in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
/*** 
    Simple jQuery Slideshow Script
    Released by Jon Raasch (jonraasch.com) under FreeBSD license: free to use or modify, not responsible for anything, etc.  Please link out to me if you like it :)
***/

function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');

    if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');

    // use this to pull the images in the order they appear in the markup
    var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
        : $('#slideshow IMG:first');

    // uncomment the 3 lines below to pull the images in random order

    // var $sibs  = $active.siblings();
    // var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * $sibs.length );
    // var $next  = $( $sibs[ rndNum ] );


    $active.addClass('last-active');

    $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 500, function() {
            $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
}

$(function() {
    setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 2500 );
});
```

I need to slide all 5 images. The problem is this stop on 2nd image and keep working fine after making a refresh. if you paste the url (or by pressing in browser) this will only show you 2 images.

if I changed animate and setinterval both to 1000 it's not animate well.

Can someone help me how to make this work.

---

it's look like a bug because if I do page refresh it's work but not when I open the page. here is the detail of bug https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872278/is-this-a-bug-in-google-chrome-slider-not-worked

Comment: probably it would be easier to help if you provide some examples i.e. on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @ted help by edit it http://jsfiddle.net/w9tnq/.

Comment: @ted now i check it's only not working for chrome.

Comment: Is that example working?

Comment: yes. if you change the image it's will work. btw change the image. I know you can't see without try with same image for every slide.

Comment: Your example is definetely not working one, thought i've add appropriate `div`. take a look for my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know for sure is that what you wanted but changed this:

```
$(function() {
    setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 2500 );
});​
```

to

```
setInterval(slideSwitch, 2500);
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/w9tnq/12/)

**P.S.**

 Works well with Chrome v.`21.0.1180.60 m`

Comment: it's broken in chrome 22 dev build. after playing a min you find only last and first image will shown.

Comment: Will be at home in a two hours, will try to reproduce your problem